# Jenkins внутри docker ошибка

Tags: docker, docker-compose, jenkins

Запускаю jenkins в докере. Получаю вот такую ошибку:

```
jenkins_1     | Can not write to /var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log. Wrong volume permissions?
jenkins_1     | touch: cannot touch '/var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log': Permission denied
```

Как решить?

docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
    jenkins:
      image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
      restart: $RESTART
      volumes:
        - ./jenkins:/var/jenkins_home
      ports:
        - 34567:8080
        - 50000:50000
```

Команда:

```
docker-compose up jenkins
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы решить проблему, нужно дать рутовые права папке, в которую производится монтирование:

```
chmod 777 ./jenkins
```

Запускаться следует из той же директории, откуда запускается `docker-compose`

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать именованый вольюм, который хранит данные при пересоздании контейнера, но директории хоста явно не соответствует:

```
services:
    jenkins:
        volumes:
          - jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
...
volumes:
    jenkins_home: {}
```

Часто такой вольюм и работает быстрее.

---

А `777` это не рутовые права, а права всем на всё.